# use of nginx server_name

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx, I have configured my consul with nginx.

It's working but I have few doubts in my configuration.

here is my configuration

```
upstream consul {
  server 127.0.0.1:8500;
} 

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://consul;
  }
}
```

this is working fine if hit http://localhost, in my machine I am able to see consul UI.

But If I change my location to **/consul**, it is giving 404.

and what is the use of server name, if I change it to **server_name mylocalserver;**

I think I should be able to run my gttp request on this address http://mylocalserver. but that is also not working.

Comment: if you change your location to /consul, it does pass /consul to the backend also, which consul has no clue about unless you did configure it for that endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add a host entry of `mylocalserver` in the host file against `127.0.0.1`, like `127.0.0.1 mylocalserver`.
2. For `/consul`, there should be a `/consul` endpoint in your code to serve your request.

As per your configuration, your `http://localhost` will be served because you have set proxypass for `"/"(all)`. It will send all requests to the application/server and will be served.

Comment: location means whatever I  provide that should serve me the request on that location whatever I provide / or /consul (both should work).In both case it should go through this IP 127.0.0.1:8500

Comment: You are right, with your configuration your all requests will be served but have you configured 'consul' directory in config.json ?   can you show me your consul config file ?